# Polygon divided into isosceles triangle in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, polygon, turtle-graphics

I wanted to draw a polygon divided into the isosceles triangle in python. I tried this code below but there seems to be an error in the variable inside angle.

why does the arrow move backwards? it was supposed to move towards the centre though. Please help me find the bug. Thanks in advance.

```
import math
import turtle
bob = turtle.Turtle()

bob.speed(1)

def triangularpolygon (t,length,n):
    angle = (n-2)*180/n
    insideangle=angle/2
    rotatingangle=180-insideangle
    centrelength = length/2/math.cos(insideangle)
    t.fd(centrelength)
    for i in range(n):
        t.fd(length)
        t.lt(rotatingangle)
        t.fd(centrelength)
        t.bk(centrelength)
        t.rt(insideangle)

triangularpolygon(bob,100,6)
```

There are no error messages. I think the value for the cosine of the angle is negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your turtle moves in the wrong direction, and not far enough, because your math is wrong.  You're mixing degrees (turtle's default) with radians (math.cos() expectation):

```
angle = (n-2)*180/n
insideangle=angle/2
centrelength = length/2/math.cos(insideangle)
```

Your `cos()` call is returning a negative value -- `forward()` with a negative value is `backward()` and vice versa.  Let's rework the math and also switch turtle to radians (not required but makes the code consistent):

```
from math import pi, sin as sine
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def triangular_polygon(turtle, length, n):
    inside_angle = (n - 2) * pi / n / 2
    rotating_angle = pi - inside_angle
    radius = length / (2 * sine(pi / n))

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(radius)
    turtle.left(rotating_angle)
    turtle.pendown()

    for _ in range(n):
        turtle.forward(length)
        turtle.left(rotating_angle)
        turtle.forward(radius)
        turtle.backward(radius)
        turtle.right(inside_angle)

screen = Screen()

bob = Turtle()
bob.radians()  # switch turtle to radians to match math functions
bob.speed('slowest')
bob.dot()  # mark the center of our screen for reference

triangular_polygon(bob, 100, 6)

bob.hideturtle()
screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]